# Unique constraint not getting respected in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-java-api

I have created a neo4j DB locally and assigned some indices and unique constraint.

Here is the :schema

```
Indexes
  ON :Actor(social_id) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Category(name)   ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
  ON (actor:Actor) ASSERT actor.social_id IS UNIQUE
  ON (category:Category) ASSERT category.name IS UNIQUE
```

Additionally I do a createIfNotFound() in my java code, where I first do a find and then create if not found.

Inspite of these two checks I still see multiple nodes of Label category and same name existing in the DB.

```
 MATCH (n:Category) WHERE n.name='garden' RETURN n

name    garden
name    garden
name    garden
name    garden
Returned 4 rows in 49 ms.
```

I am not sure what I am missing, and why is the unique constraint not being honored.

Comment: Can you drop and recreated the unique constraint? I assume you will get an error here.

Comment: Did you create the constraint after those nodes were in?  If not, please post the code of your `createIfNotFound`

Comment: @Stefen : yes on dropping and recreating I do see the error.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Yes I did create the node after adding the constraint. Unfortunately I got impatient and dumped the code and rewrote it all afresh. Its working fine now. Also I posted on the neo4j cummunity forum and seems like they have found the bug. I will test it by resurrecting my old code and testing this weekend. Once resolved I would post the solution and root cause here.

Comment: Thanks @Stefen and FrobberOfBits, appreciate your interest and suggestions.